# Summing in a Dataframe over one column while keeping others

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum

In a pandas Dataframe `df` I have columns likes this:

```
    NAME    KEYWORD  AMOUNT  INFO
0   orange  fruit    13      from italy
1   potato  veggie   7       from germany
2   potato  veggie   9       from germany
3   orange  fruit    8       from italy
4   potato  veggie   6       from germany
```

Doing a `groupby KEYWORD` operation I want to build the sum of the `AMOUNT` values per group **and keep from the other columns always the first value**, so that the result reads:

```
    NAME    KEYWORD  AMOUNT  INFO
0   orange  fruit    21      from italy
1   potato  veggie   22      from germany
```

I tried

```
df.groupby('KEYWORD).sum()
```

but this "summarises" over all columns, i.e I get

```
    NAME                KEYWORD  AMOUNT  INFO
0   orangeorange        fruit    21      from italyfrom italy
1   potatopotatopotato  veggie   22      from germanyfrom germanyfrom germany
```

Then I tried to use different functions for different columns:

```
df.groupby('KEYWORD).agg({'AMOUNT': sum, 'NAME': first, ....})
```

with

```
def first(f_arg, *args):
    return f_arg
```

But this gives me unfortunately a "`ValueError: function does not reduce`" error.

So I am a bit at a loss. How can I apply `sum` only to the `AMOUNT` column, while keeping the others?

Comment: pandas has a builtin `first` function. You can invoke it with agg by passing a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with a custom aggfunc dict.

```
f = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['KEYWORD']), 'first')
f['AMOUNT'] = sum

df = df.groupby('KEYWORD', as_index=False).agg(f)
df

  KEYWORD    NAME  AMOUNT          INFO
0   fruit  orange      21    from italy
1  veggie  potato      22  from germany
```

`dict.fromkeys` gives me a nice way of generalising this for N number of columns. If column order matters, add a [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) operation at the end:

```
df = df.groupby('KEYWORD', as_index=False).agg(f).reindex(columns=df.columns)
df

     NAME KEYWORD  AMOUNT          INFO
0  orange   fruit      21    from italy
1  potato  veggie      22  from germany
```

Comment: Thanks heaps, @COLDSPEED. So I was close. :-)  Still I don't understand why the aggregate function works when provided as a string `'first'`, while a proper function reference `first` does not work. Is my definition of `first` wrong? I don't understand why: It *does* transform  many arguments into one value of type of the first argument. That's what aggregation does, right?

Comment: @halloleo you were certainly close. But I don't think your function was correct. It should accept a series and return the first row as another array/series, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thanks for your reply. - Yes, my function does not play correctly with pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by column `KEYWORD` and then [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) aggregate values:

```
df=df.drop_duplicates('KEYWORD').assign(AMOUNT=df.groupby('KEYWORD')['AMOUNT'].sum().values)
print (df)
     NAME KEYWORD  AMOUNT          INFO
0  orange   fruit      21    from italy
1  potato  veggie      22  from germany
```